# PyTorch: "one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation"

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training a PyTorch RNN on a text file of song lyrics to predict the next character given a character.

Here's how my RNN is defined:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim

class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        
        # from input, previous hidden state to new hidden state
        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
        
        # from input, previous hidden state to output
        self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, output_size)
        
        # softmax on output
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1)
    
    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        
        combined = torch.cat((input, hidden), 1)
        
        #get new hidden state
        hidden = self.i2h(combined)
        
        #get output
        output = self.i2o(combined)
        
        #apply softmax
        output = self.softmax(output)
        return output, hidden
    
    def initHidden(self): 
        return torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)

rnn = RNN(input_size = num_chars, hidden_size = 200, output_size = num_chars)
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

lr = 0.01
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(rnn.parameters(), lr = lr)
```

Here's my training function:

```
def train(train, target):
    
    hidden = rnn.initHidden()
    
    loss = 0
    
    for i in range(len(train)):
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # get output, hidden state from rnn given input char, hidden state
        output, hidden = rnn(train[i].unsqueeze(0), hidden)

        #returns the index with '1' - indentifying the index of the right character
        target_class = (target[i] == 1).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
        
        loss += criterion(output, target_class)
        
    
        loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
        optimizer.step()
        
        print("done " + str(i) + " loop")
    
    return output, loss.item() / train.size(0)
```

When I run my training function, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [274, 74]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 5; expected version 3 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

Interestingly, it makes it through two complete loops of the training function before giving me that error.

Now, when I remove the `retain_graph = True` from `loss.backward()`, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved variables after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved variables after calling backward.
```

It shouldn't be trying to go backward through the graph multiple times here. Perhaps the graph is not getting cleared between training loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are accumulating your loss values (and at the same time, the computation graphs associated attached to them) on variable `loss`, here:

```
    loss += criterion(output, target_class)
```

In turn, this means at every iteration you are trying to backpropagate through the current **and previous** loss values that were computed in previous inferences. In this particular instance where you are looping through your dataset, it isn't the right thing to do.

A simple fix is to accumulate `loss`'s underlying value, *i.e.* the scalar value, not the tensor itself, using [`item`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html). And, backpropagate on the current loss tensor:

```
total_loss = 0
    
for i in range(len(train)):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output, hidden = rnn(train[i].unsqueeze(0), hidden)
    target_class = (target[i] == 1).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
        
    loss = criterion(output, target_class)
    loss.backward()

    total_loss += loss.item()
```

Since you are updating the model's parameter straight after having done the backpropagation, you don't need to retain the graph in memory.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Explanation makes sense.